# Closing file without saving

Tags: vba, visio

I have a code block (which works) to open a file.

```
Dim AppVisio
Set AppVisio = CreateObject("visio.InvisibleApp")
Dim vsoDoc
Set vsoDoc = AppVisio.Documents.Open("PathName\Drawing1.vsd")
```

However, when this file is already open, I want it to be automatically closed without saving changes.

I could not find code such as

```
AppVisio.Documents.Close ("PathName\Drawing1.vsd")
```

Any other options to force close the file should it be open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Dim vsoDoc
> ```

You've declared it as an *implicit* `Variant` - this would be equivalent:

```
Dim vsoDoc As Variant
```

And if you place a breakpoint immediately after the `Set vsoDoc =` statement, go to the immediate pane (Ctrl+G) and type

```
?TypeName(vsoDoc)
```

You'll see that it will print `Document`. Hence, you can declare it with a `Document` type instead:

```
Dim vsoDoc As Document
```

And then when you want to close this `vsoDoc`, you work with *that* object and call its `Close` method:

```
Set vsoDoc = AppVisio.Documents.Open("PathName\Drawing1.vsd")
'do stuff...
vsoDoc.Close
```

That `vsoDoc` variable *is* your document object. Declaring it `As Document` will give you IntelliSense/AutoComplete so when you type the dot in `vsoDoc.`, you'll see a drop-down in the editor showing you all the document's members.

If you're already in Visio, there's no need to late-bind everything; you *already* have a reference to the Visio object model. Early binding makes it much easier to know which types are involved and what their members are.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is part of the Document object (not Documents)
[Click Here to see the Document Close Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767415.aspx)

Comment: Yes but how would you suggest closing an invisible document. The documentations at MSDN suggests closing an active document. What would you suggest to get the above document closed?

Is there anyway to 'capture' the window? (assuming its opened and force close it) with 'on error resume next'?

Comment: Thanks all for the help!